# Aspx page alignment problems

Tags: html, asp.net, css

On my website, doesn't matter what I do, I cannot seem to center anything in any of the pages on my website. Everything aligns on the side, or on random places on the page. The only solution ise to use absolute positioning, which does not work very well and is very inconvenient, since I have to do everything manually, because each picture/table needs different properties. Here is what the website looks like, aligning on the side - http://i43.tinypic.com/hvb67m.jpg

This (show members) page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <div style=" font-family:'Times New Roman';  " align="center">   
        <img src= "./Images/ShowMembers.png" alt="ShowMembers"  />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
            <%=str %>

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

The css stylesheet:

```
body 
{
    background: url(/upload/Images/Background.jpg) no-repeat; 
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-position:bottom;

    font-size:18px;
    font-family: Arial;
    direction:rtl
}
#wrapper{
margin:0 auto;
}
a
{
     text-decoration:none;
     color:Blue;
}

.noBorder
{
    border-style:none;
}

td 
{
    vertical-align:central;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The masterpage has nothing relevant.

I would appereciate any type of advice, thanks.

Comment: have you tried using text-align:center on the parent element of whatever you are trying to center? the only one i see that has text-align:center is a td in your css, but there are no td tags in your code shown.

Comment: the page still looks the same...

Comment: what did you change? what are you trying to center: the text, the image, the div, all?

Comment: i tried adding text-align:center to the stylesheet, then to the parent div of the logo, and it changed nothing. i am trying to center everything on the page

Comment: how did you add text-align:center in the css? update your question anytime you change your code. not everything uses the same style to get centered. text, images usually center with text-align:center on its parent element, while divs usually need something like margin-left:auto margin-right:auto (if not using position:absolute;) and it has to have a defined width (divs default to a 100% width so it cant be centered).

Comment: if you want ur wraper to center than use a particular width of wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVv75/1/)):

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    .center_outer
    {
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
    .center_inner
    {
        position: relative;
        left: -50%;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="center_outer">
    <div class="center_inner">
               <!-- Put your contents (which needs to be centered) here --!>
        Whatever contents here get centered.
    </div>
</div>
```

This will center any contents inside the `div.center_inner`. Even with floated (no width mentioned) `div`s. Wrap the `div` inside `#Content2` with these two divs.